# Run modprobe on startup

Tags: kernel, startup, wacom

I need to run `sudo modprobe wacom` at startup to prevent an unrecoverable kernel panic (a blackscreen drop to terminal with repeating 1second audio looping and zero responsiveness) from occurring when a standard Wacom Intous (CTH-480) tablet is plugged into USB port on stock Xubuntu 14.04 LTS. I believe mainline kernel fixed this issue some time ago.

Where is the preferred location for this configuration? It must be run as `root`.

I have seen this
[How to run scripts on start up?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/814/how-to-run-scripts-on-start-up) but I am unsure which answer would work for the required permission level of `modprobe`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can add the line `modprobe wacom` to `/etc/rc.local` and it will get executed on boot with root privileges.

Comment: This would have it load relatively late in the boot sequence.

Comment: I find that the command has to be delayed a bit, eg: `(sleep 15s && [your command...]) &`

Answer (score 13):

Check if you have a `/etc/modules-load.d/wacom.conf` file. If not, run this command:

```
sudo -i
echo wacom > /etc/modules-load.d/wacom.conf
```

This will create a configuration file ending in `.conf` and with content `wacom`.

Reboot and it will be loaded by systemd at boot time.

Comment: This is the correct method. rc.local is deprecated and doesn't work correctly and I also found I needed to use sleep if I hacked it, but this method just works and is "proper"

Answer (score 9):

Just edit the file `/etc/modules` and add a new line with `wacom`.

You can reboot to check if it works.

---

If you do not have `/etc/modules`, try this one instead:

`/etc/modules-load.d/modules.conf`

Even if it should be not a problem since in Debian-like or Ubuntu-like ecc. they are symlinked.